# Android ImageView positon in LinearLayout

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I want a small Image to appear in the right side of my ListView, but when i try my TextViews pushes it out of the "app" so its not visible. I have tried working on the gravity, but i cant seem to get it right. Is it possible to place it as i want or do i have to do it in a RelativeLauoyt ?
Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="80dip" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dip">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#004b23"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_marginRight="30sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:textColor="#cfae78"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#cfae78"
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the ImageView i want to place to the right side of my ListView.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@drawable/day"
    android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your 'inner' linear layout has an attribute `layout_width="fill_parent"` this will cause your inner linear layout to take up all the remaining horizontal space. To get it to work change the linear layout's layout_width attribute to a smaller value say 150dip.

That is, `layout_width="150dip"`

Also, its not your textView thats pushing out your image but the layout_width attribute of your linear layout

P.S I also recommend you use a relative layout.

Comment: Would i just have to replace my inner linearlayout with relativelayout, or also the "outer" linearlayout ?

Comment: Replace the outer layout with a relative layout and use the answer tony provided. If you want to stick to the linear layout, change the layout_width parameter as provided in the answer.

Comment: I think i will try replacing the outer layout. I will return when i get it right.

Answer (score 0):

I would always recommend using RelativeLayout (but it's just personal preference).

Using RelativeLayout you would need to:

Listview:  (Align Parent Left, to Left of ImageView)
ImageView: (Align Parent Right, Width: wrap content)

That should achieve what you want.